# Matching up fields in different tables using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fields-attributes, table

I work for a University, and we have some utility/site people go out with their GPS and shoot points pretty often when there are new projects, construction, etc. The data dictionary that they have created has some field names that are longer than 10 characters, so when they export to shapefiles, the fields are being cut off to only contain the allowed limit. Once they bring in the shapefile into our existing base map, they copy and then paste the new items into the existing sde feature class, the data that is contained in the truncated fields won't copy. So, then they have to go in and redo some of the fields that didn't copy over.

I know that fields have to match between tables in order to copy/paste data, but is there some kind of script, code, or work around that can match up these fields?

I was hoping that there is some kind of field name match. for example, something that i could use to say that create_dat from the gps export file would equal create_date in the existing feature class.

I have attached an image of both tables and what data will and won't copy over.

[image]

Comment: If you load data into a feature class cant you match the fields from a drop down list? or is that too labourious?

Comment: Or you could use a short name and alias in your SDE

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this field mappings help document.  I think it is doing exactly what you want.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z00000014000000